# how to replace value of variable in a string by javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I want to replace value of "var1"(it's a variable) with "" in String str in javaScript.
But this code doesn't work and str hasn't be changed!

```
var var1 = $("#elementId1").html();
var str = $("#elementId2").val();
str = str.replace(var1, '');
alert(str);
```

for example :

```
var1 = 'aaa';    
str = 'bbbb,aaa,ccccc';    
str = str.replace(var1, '');    
alert(str) shows bbbb,aaa,ccccc again not bbbb,,ccccc
```

Comment: html() - returns html markup of the selector, val() - returns value of the selected input field. If i am not wrong you want to replace existence of  input field value(str) into html (var1) with blank. Rather than existence of html(var1) into input field value (str)

Comment: nothing is wrong with your code. Just use double code instead of single one.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var substr = "aa";
var str = "aa bb cc dd";

document.write(str.replace(substr, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var1 = "aaa";    
str = "bbbb,aaa,ccccc";    
str = str.replace(var1, "");    
alert(str)
```

Check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1meb158L/)